# rails 6: no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been trying to learn ruby(2.6.3) on rails(6.0.1) by following a project to make an Instagram clone.
When I try to create a new post I get "no implicit conversion of String into Integer app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:8:in `create' ". I'm confused because I do not see a string to int so i'm wondering if it is something i'm missing with ruby. I've tried updating my gem versions and also tried adding the "strong_parameters" gem but that did not seem to fix my problem. Thank you for any insight as to what i'm doing wrong

Post_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

def new
 @post = Post.new
end

def create
 @post = Post.new(post_params)

if @post.save
  redirect_to dashboard_path, flash: {success: "Post was created successfully!"}
else
  redirect_to new_post_path, flash: {danger: "Post failed to save!"}
 end
end

def show
end

private

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:image, :image_cache)
end
end
```

Posts table migrate

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
def change
create_table :posts do |t|
  t.string :image
  t.boolean :active
  t.references :account
  t.timestamps
  end
end
end
```

Post Model

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Post table schema

```
create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "image"
t.boolean "active"
t.bigint "account_id"
t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
t.index ["account_id"], name: "index_posts_on_account_id"
end
```

Full stack trace

```
carrierwave (2.0.2) lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:312:in `chmod'
carrierwave (2.0.2) lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:312:in `chmod!'
carrierwave (2.0.2) lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:220:in `copy_to'
carrierwave (2.0.2) lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:141:in `cache!'
carrierwave (2.0.2) lib/carrierwave/mounter.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in cache'
carrierwave (2.0.2) lib/carrierwave/mounter.rb:176:in `handle_error'
carrierwave (2.0.2) lib/carrierwave/mounter.rb:47:in `block in cache'
carrierwave (2.0.2) lib/carrierwave/mounter.rb:46:in `map'
carrierwave (2.0.2) lib/carrierwave/mounter.rb:46:in `cache'
carrierwave (2.0.2) lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:146:in `image='
carrierwave (2.0.2) lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:373:in `image='
carrierwave (2.0.2) lib/carrierwave/orm/activerecord.rb:75:in `image='
activemodel (6.0.1) lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:51:in `public_send'
activemodel (6.0.1) lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:51:in `_assign_attribute'
activemodel (6.0.1) lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:44:in `block in _assign_attributes'
activemodel (6.0.1) lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:43:in `each'
activemodel (6.0.1) lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:43:in `_assign_attributes'
activerecord (6.0.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:22:in `_assign_attributes'
activemodel (6.0.1) lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `assign_attributes'
activerecord (6.0.1) lib/active_record/core.rb:326:in `initialize'
activerecord (6.0.1) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:70:in `new'
activerecord (6.0.1) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:70:in `new'
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:8:in `create'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:196:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (6.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:135:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:33:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (6.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (6.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (6.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `instrument'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (6.0.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (6.0.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:191:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:252:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:51:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:49:in `block in serve'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:837:in `call'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:648:in `call'
activerecord (6.0.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:567:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:32:in `call'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (6.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (6.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (6.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (6.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
railties (6.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (6.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:83:in `call'
webpacker (4.2.0) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:23:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.6.5) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
railties (6.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:526:in `call'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:681:in `handle_request'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Carrierwave config

CarrierWave.configure do |config| config.fog_credentials = { provider: 'AWS', aws_access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'], } config.storage = :fog config.permissions = "0666" config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/" config.fog_directory = ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY'] config.fog_attributes = { 'Cache-Control' => "max-age=#{365.day.to_i}" }end

Comment: Is `app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:8:` the topmost line in the error stacktrace? I don't see anything in `@post = Post.new(post_params)` that would have caused that error. Hmm...

Comment: Can you paste your schema for `posts` table

Comment: What's on your Post model?

Comment: More likely you are trying to assign a string to a field in your Post model that is defined as an integer in your database.

Comment: Could you post the full error trace please @taylormorse?

Comment: Sorry for the long turn around time, I have added the relevant requested information. If i'm missing anything please just let me know

Comment: @SRack sorry forgot to at you

Comment: Does :image_cache not need to be defined in your Post table?

Answer (score 1):

almost always when I see this, it is passing a string into the index of an array. Sorry to be vague, but I don't see where that would happen in your code.